# Installing packages in jupyterhub kubespawner nodes

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have a jupyterhub running over a kubernetes cluster with kubespawner.  As I understand it, kubespawner is, via kubernetes, spinning up dockers on my cluster that have their own python environment and storage area.

For some user, I am attempting to import rpy2 (or whatever, it's not important), and the package is not installed.

My questions:

Where do these dockers get their python environment (e.g. Is there a dockerfile I can edit somewhere)?

How to I get rpy2 installed for just that one docker session?

How do I get rpy2 installed for that user (if possible)?

How do I get rpy2 installed for everyone on the hub?

Comment: Showing your Kubernetes configs will help. Which jupyterhub version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the official images (jupyterhub/jupyterhub) you'll find  all installation steps in the related Dockerfile on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/~/dockerfile/) or on [Github](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/Dockerfile).

To install a package for just one (already running) container. You can use `kubectl exec your-pod -- pip install xxx`

To install it for every deployment you'd have to provide your own container and include that in your Deployment. I assume this would result in merging with the [rpy2 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rpy2/rpy2/~/dockerfile/), which could be done with a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM jupyterhub/singleuser
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install \
   https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/get/default.tar.gz && \
   rm -rf /root/.cache
```

Comment: You aren't extending the ``jupyterhub/jupyterhub`` image to add the package. You need to extend ``jupyterhub/singleuser`` image and then configure JupyterHub to use your custom image instead of ``juypyterhub/singleuser`` when spawning an individual notebook instance. https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyterhub/singleuser/

Comment: Graham thx for the comment ... I updated my answer - I'm not a jupytherhub user, but tried to give a rough overview what could be done to solve the question.